# Issue trying to save emojis in my CSV file

Tags: csv, email, emoji, subject

I would like to use emojis in my subject, but I need to get it from a flat file. Do you know how can I save emojis in a CSV that will be used in the email subject?
Ps: I know how to do it for the body of the email using [HTML entities](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/icon), but not for the subject 😥

Answer (score 0):

You can store a hexadecimal unicode value of your Emoji. But these values (here F09F98A5), have to be interpreted.

Usually, these values will be interpreted by a Specific OS or a WebEngine (using HTML Entities in the body of an email)

Note you can display a light version of a Emoji with the font Segoe UI Symbol.

To answer your question, you need to know how the recipient of your emails will interpret the data of an email subject.